# Incorrect images sometimes assigned to UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, kingfisher

I have a group chat with a few hundred people in it and when I scroll quickly, sometimes either user images jump from something to something else or incorrect images are shown for a user.

I've followed a few other SO posts but I still seem to be doing something incorrectly. Anything stand out here and something that I can do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

```
final class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    private lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        return imageView
    }()

    // MARK: – Init

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        selectionStyle = .none

        addSubview(profileImageView)

        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        constrain(profileImageView) {
            let size: CGFloat = 36
            $0.width == size
            $0.height == size
            $0.bottom == $0.superview!.bottom - CGFloat(3)
            $0.left == $0.superview!.left + CGFloat(12)
        }
    }


    func configure(with presentable: CellPresentable) {
        self.presentable = presentable

        if let sender = presentable.sender, presentable.isFirstMessage {
            profileImageView.setImage(url: (sender.object(forKey: "picture") as? PFFile)?.url, fallbackText: presentable.username)
        } else {
            PFUser.query()?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: presentable.message.senderUserId).getFirstObjectInBackground { [weak self] user, error in
                self?.profileImageView.setImage(url: (user?.object(forKey: "picture") as? PFFile)?.url, fallbackText: presentable.username)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Reuse -

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        profileImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        profileImageView.image = nil
    }

}
```

In my View Controller:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell") as! MessageCell
let presentable = CellPresentable(for: message, isFirstMessage: isFirstMessage, isLastMessage: isLastMessage)
cell.configure(with: presentable)

return cell
```

Comment: You can check if your cell image url is equal to image url which you download

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a race condition that's related to PFUser.query()'s getFirstObjectInBackground being asynchronous and your cells being dequeued and reused by the system before that function's closure returns.

In order to save memory, the system only creates a limited number of cells and reuses them when your collection view or tableview scrolls. It then dequeues these cells and reconfigures them with data relevant to their index paths.

When you call getFirstObjectInBackground(), its closure captures **self**. Your issue is that **self** at this point is being reused. It's located at another index path and is configured with different data so the image that just returned to you asynchronously is no longer fresh or relevant.

My advice would be to figure out how to cancel those image requests if you know you will not need them because the cell has scrolled past being visible and sanity checking inside the closure to make sure the item is still what you expect it to be like this:

```
 guard presentable == self?.presentable else {return}
 self?.profileImageView.setImage(url: (user?.object(forKey: "picture") as? PFFile)?.url, fallbackText: presentable.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in configure function in MessageCell

```
profileImageView.image = nil
```

So newly code of function :

```
func configure(with presentable: CellPresentable) {
    self.presentable = presentable
    profileImageView.image = nil
    if let sender = presentable.sender, presentable.isFirstMessage {
        profileImageView.setImage(url: (sender.object(forKey: "picture") as? PFFile)?.url, fallbackText: presentable.username)
    } else {
        PFUser.query()?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: presentable.message.senderUserId).getFirstObjectInBackground { [weak self] user, error in
            self?.profileImageView.setImage(url: (user?.object(forKey: "picture") as? PFFile)?.url, fallbackText: presentable.username)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers are helpful but what really moved the needle was realizing that I after I did my `PFUser.query()`, I wasn't storing that fetched user everywhere so if I fetched user 5 once, I fetched them every time their images appeared. That's what was causing the delay. Instead, I just removed that call and used an alternative for those users (since those users aren't in my group anymore) and scrolling greatly improved.